# Enable access to win 10 shares via network icons for OS's above ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, samba

I have searched at length for instructions but am only able to find workarounds such as mounts and bookmarks and the like. Is anyone interested in restoring a seamless traditional share access as was available in earlier versions?  Why cant the OS be modified so as to enable correction via upgrades or something. I can access ubuntu servers and clients from windows via network folders, why not the reverse?
Is this not important?  Is there not enough demand for this?  Is this impossible to do?

Comment: Because of a bug (   https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1828107 )  that was created because they fixed an earlier bug (  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1778322?comments=all ) Nautilus cannot "discover" then "connect" to any Samba / SMB server that has disabled SMB1. That includes Win10 at the moment and in the future Ubuntu 20.

In retrospect they shouldn't have fixed the earlier bug but it is what it is. The workarounds are the ones you already mentioned: Connect to Server, smb://win10hostname.local in Nautilus or a CIFS mount.

Comment: Thanks M.  But I'm using NT1 on the Ubuntu side and have enabled smb 1.0 on the windows side.  Should that not correct the SMB1 compatibility issue?

Comment: Sure but then you have to play within the old netbios rules. "name resolve order" has to be set to have bcast first, etc... All the stuff Microsoft tried to get rid of 20 years ago with Win2K. Much more reliable just to connect to the server / share with its mDNS host name.

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but my point is using nt1 and smb1 do not correct the problem, suggesting that SMB1 compatibility may not be the only obstacle.

Comment: To Moribus1, concur with ur comments and warnings.  Thanks much.